# CVE-2021-44228 - LOG4J - Does SNOWFLAKE contain any vulnerability related to LOG4J? Thanks

Tags: log4j

Does SNOWFLAKE contain any vulnerability related to LOG4J?
I want to confirm if SNOWFLAKE contains any vulnerability.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[Snowflake's official announcement](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/No-Snowflake-exposure-to-Apache-Log4j-vulnerability-CVE-2021-44228) for this is

> The Snowflake platform does not utilize Log4j as part of our production environment or any client connectors. The Snowflake Security and Incident Response teams have implemented additional threat detection measures and are actively monitoring this issue should further response be required.