# Log4j Bug in Snowflake

Tags: security, log4j, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently checking if I got any security issues due to the log4j bug. The only post regarding Snowflake in this topic I found just told me Snowflake is definitely using log4j.

Is there any offical statement if the data is secure?
Anything we can do on ourselfs to secure it?

Best
Nic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CVE-2021-44228 - LOG4J - Does SNOWFLAKE contain any vulnerability related to LOG4J? Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70339635/cve-2021-44228-log4j-does-snowflake-contain-any-vulnerability-related-to-log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the official announcement from Snowflake here:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/No-Snowflake-exposure-to-Apache-Log4j-vulnerability-CVE-2021-44228